# Junit 4 how to initialize in test suite and pass it to test classes

Tags: java, junit, test-suite

Is there a way in Junit4 to pass some pre-initialized data like http connections that you initialize using say '@ClassRule' in the class annotated with '@RunWith(Suite.class)' to all child (i.e. suite) test classes? Also how to ensure that the classes in the suite cannot be run individually?

e.g.

```
class A {
    private HttpClient client;
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        client.execute(...);
        ...
    }
 }

 @RunWith(Suite.class)
 @Suite.SuiteClasses({A.class})
 public class Suite {
     private static HttpClient client;
     @ClassRule
     public static ExternalResource resource= new ExternalResource() {
         @Override
         protected void before() throws Throwable {
             client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         } 
     }
```

Thanks,

Paddy

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can achieve that with JUnit.

The only possibility I see is to use an abstract class and inherit that one in every test class.

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {
  @ClassRule
  public static ExternalResource resource= new ExternalResource() {
    //...
  }
}

public class MyTest extends AbstractTest {
}
```

> Also how to ensure that the classes in the suite cannot be run individually?

I don't think that is possible either.

**But why would you want that?**
After fixing a single failing test, do you really want to re-run all tests to check if one test is working?
(Of course, the fix could have introduced side effects but you can re-run all tests when you know that your fixed test is working.)
Moreover, the tests should be able to run independently.

Comment: Indeed you can mutualize/factorize by inheritance or in many ways (composition ...). But In general as stated by nrainer, Junit tests should not depend on each other. You will then struggle with many tools because they will assume your tests are atomic. For instance, with Maven and surefire, tests can run in parallel, etc etc ...

Comment: Hi @nrainer, if you use abstract class, will it be available to sub-classes as instance variable? I do not want the somewhat ugly way of referring TestSuite.configuredResource (where configuredResource is a static variable I set within ClassRule's before method) ? Also the reason why I asked if individual test classes can be prevented is because I want some client initialization to happen at the start of the suite and be used by individual classes. My aim to break the tests into two or more classes just for maintainability but not do the costly initialization every time (only at suite start).

Comment: "Will it be available to sub-classes as instance variable?"
It depends on the modifier, but I don't know whether it is required to be public or not.

"[...] why I asked if individual test classes can be prevented [...]" That is not a problem, simply add a condition.
If the client variable is null, do the initialization and assign it, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the out-of-the-box `Runners` of JUnit you would get any access from a test `Suite` to its child tests. Instantiation of the test classes is done internally in the framework.

If you want to pass information/state from one test to another, I'd suppose to implement some kind of "context". E.g. a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with a static Getter and Setter for the context that allows your suite to store an `Object` and to read it later on from your tests.